# Getting raw SQL query after a prepared statement is built on android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making an Android app and using a SQLite database. In particular I'm using the `rawQuery` method on a database obtained through a `SQLiteOpenHelper`. The query I build makes use of the `?` marks as placeholders for the real values, which are passed along as an array of objects (e.g., `select * from table where id = ?`).

The question is, is it possible to get the query with the marks already replaced, at least from the cursor returned from the `rawQuery` method? I mean something like `select * from table where id = 56`. This would be useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: you can use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` for that

Comment: I checked that class, but it does not seem to allow the building of a join query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The `?` values are not bound at the SQL level but deeper, and there's no "result" SQL after binding the values.

Variable binding is a part of the sqlite3 C API, and the Android SQLite APIs just provide a thin wrapper on top. http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

For debugging purposes you can log your SQL with the `?`, and log the values of your bind arguments.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know, even if I hoped there was a way around this :( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could form it as a string like this

```
int id = 56;
String query = "select * from table where id = '" + id + "'";
```

and then use it as a rawQuery like this (if I understood your question properly)

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
```

You can also use the SQLiteQueryBuilder. Here is an example with a join query:

```
//Create new querybuilder
SQLiteQueryBuilder _QB = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

//Specify books table and add join to categories table (use full_id for joining categories table)
_QB.setTables(BookColumns.TABLENAME + 
    " LEFT OUTER JOIN " + CategoryColumns.TABLENAME + " ON " + 
    BookColumns.CATEGORY + " = " + CategoryColumns.FULL_ID);

//Order by records by title
_OrderBy = BookColumns.BOOK_TITLE + " ASC";

//Open database connection
SQLiteDatabase _DB = fDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

//Get cursor
Cursor _Result = _QB.query(_DB, null, null, null, null, null, _OrderBy);
```

Comment: This is a way I could get it done, but I was asking specifically for when I'm using the ? placeholders (suppose I want to avoid raw string concatenation).

Comment: take a look at the edit for an example with SQLiteQueryBuilder in this case (with join operation)